# C# linq: Check multiple conditions on a list on the same property field

Tags: c#, list, linq

Am trying to get 'testNumber' when 'name' matches with 'AAA' & 'BBB' like below, but '_check' bool field is false'. What am I missing?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var _tests = new List<testDetails>()
        {
            new testDetails { testNumber = "1111111", name =  "AAA"  },
            new testDetails { testNumber = "1111111",  name =  "BBB"   },
            new testDetails { testNumber = "1111111",  name =  "CCC"   },
            new testDetails { testNumber = "1111111",  name =  "DDD"   },
            new testDetails { testNumber = "222222", name =  "AAA"  },
            new testDetails { testNumber = "22222",  name =  "BBB"   },
            new testDetails { testNumber = "33333",  name =  "CCC"   },
            new testDetails { testNumber = "11111",  name =  "EEE"   },
            new testDetails { testNumber = "33333",  name =  "CCC"   },
            new testDetails { testNumber = "55555",  name =  "DDD"   }
        };
    
        foreach (var _test in _tests.GroupBy(x => x.testNumber).ToList())
        {
            bool _check = _test.Where(o => o.name.Equals("AAA") && o.name.Equals("BBB")).Any();
           //_test.Any(p => p.name.Equals("AAA") && p.name.Equals("BBB")) - false
            //why is _check false?
            if (_check)
            {
                string _string = string.Empty;
                _string = _test.Where(o => o.name.Equals("AAA") && o.name.Equals("BBB")).Select(q => q.testNumber).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe what you are looking for is :

```
bool _check = _test.Any(o => o.name.Equals("AAA")) && _test.Any(o => o.name.Equals("BBB"));
```

This will check if your group contain at least one testDetails with "AAA" and one with "BBB"

Your current code  cannot work because one instance of `testDetails` cannot have his name equal to both "AAA" and "BBB" at the same time

Comment: I think I`ll have to stick to having two conditions like above. I misunderstood my && condition. Thank!

Answer (score 3):

You are currently checking if the **same object** has both the name `"AAA"` **and** the name `"BBB"`.

Well the same object cannot have both.  So you should be using an **OR** statement instead.

```
bool _check = _test.Where(o => o.name.Equals("AAA") || o.name.Equals("BBB")).Any();
```

Comment: How is this logically right? I have to check if both AAA & BBB present for the number in the list. Considering above, AAA & ZZZ can also be true.

Comment: @Deson  You have separate distinct objects, each one created by using "new"   So new testDetails { testNumber = "1111111", name =  "AAA"  }, is not the same object as new testDetails { testNumber = "1111111",  name =  "BBB"   }, but a separate one.

Comment: no this wont work for approach of question,  worng answer, bottom one is right

Answer (score 2):

```
o.name.Equals("AAA") && o.name.Equals("BBB")
```

This code always false, maybe what you want is this code.

```
o.name.Equals("AAA") || o.name.Equals("BBB")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool _check = _test.Where(o => o.name.Equals("AAA") && o.name.Equals("BBB")).Any();
```

`o.name` cannot equal "AAA" and "BBB" at the same time. Should it be an or operation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's as simple as you've got confused between an AND and an OR - the query you've done is getting all values where name is "AAA" AND name is "BBB"; but if name is "AAA", name cannot be "BBB".

If you swap the && to an || then you'd be getting the values where name is either "AAA" or "BBB"